# Error in the configuration Proguard using Vuforia

Tags: android, vuforia, android-proguard

I'm trying to put the Vuforia in proguard settings and the error log is being presented:

> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGR7Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.osterhoutgroup.api.ext.ExtendDisplay
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView$Layout
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView$RenderMode
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView$Layout
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView$RenderMode
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView$Layout
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView$RenderMode
>
> Warning:com.qualcomm.ar.pl.ODGX6Controller: can't find referenced
>   class com.ti.s3d.S3DView
>
> Warning:there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>
> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please
>   correct the above warnings first.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

My proguard:

```
#tests

#-keep class com.qualcomm.** { *; }

-keep class com.vuforia.** { *; }

#-keep class com.qualcomm.ar.pl.** { *; }

-keep class com.vuforia.ar.pl.** { *; }

#-dontwarn class com.qualcomm.ar.pl.** { *; }

#-dontwarn class com.vuforia.ar.pl.**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fwiw I'm using following

```
-keep class com.vuforia.** { *; }
-keep interface com.vuforia.** { *; }

-keep class com.osterhoutgroup.** { *; }
-keep class com.ti.s3d.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.vuforia.ar.**
```

Comment: This one worked for me too. Unity 2017.2.0b9, built-in Vuforia support.